# How do I integrate this piecewise function with Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I came across the question of what percent of numbers from 0 to 1 have a logerithm whose floor is even. What I did was I made a piecewise function: `Piecewise[{{1, EvenQ[Floor[Log[x]]] == True}}, 0]`. If I plot the function  I get:
[image: Piecwise function plotted] 
so it clearly recognizes this function. However, when I try to integrate the function from 0 to 1 with `Integrate[Piecewise[{{1, EvenQ[Floor[Log[x]]] == True}}, 0], {x, 0, 1}]`, the result that it gives me is `0`. This is clearly false, as all outputs are either 0 or 1. I tried integrating from .1 to 1 and I still get 0. I even tried integrating from 0.2 to 0.3 where the only outputs are 1, and therefore the integral should be 0.1, but I get an output of 0. I tried doing it with conditionals, but I still get the output as 0. Is there something I am doing wrong or is Mathematica just failing to integrate it?

Comment: `EvenQ[a]` evaluates to `False` immidiately for symbolic input, thats why you get 0, to avoid it use something without the Q, e.g. `a/2 ∈ Integers`

Comment: `Mod[...<Integer-valued expression>..., 2] == 0` is a standard way to "algebraically" represent the condition for being even. So `Mod[Floor[Log[x]], 2] == 0`. But one problem, I think, is that there are infinitely many singular points on the interval of integration. I don't know if/when Mma is/will be programmed to handle that in `Integrate`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this gives the answer, if I didn't get mixed up about even/odd.

```
Sum[Integrate[Boole[Mod[n, 2] == 0], {x, Exp[-n], Exp[-n + 1]}],
 {n, Infinity}]
(*  1/(1 + E)  *)
```

I couldn't figure out how to get `Integrate` (or `DSolve`) to handle the condition on `Log[x]`.  But here's a way to approximate it with `NDSolve`:

```
Block[{x0 = 1/10^6}, 
 NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == sgn[x], y[1] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[Mod[Log[x], 1] == 0, sgn[x] -> 1 - sgn[x]], 
   sgn[1] == 0}, -y[x0], {x, x0, 1}, DiscreteVariables -> sgn]
 ]
(*  0.268941  *)

1/(1 + E) // N
(*  0.268941  *)
```

*Addendum*

To evaluate to arbitrary precision:

```
Block[{prec = 100},
  NIntegrate[
   Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= Mod[u, 2] < 1}}, 0] Exp[u],
   {u, Log[10^-prec], Sequence @@ Range[Ceiling@Log[10^-prec], 0]},
   WorkingPrecision -> prec]
  ] - 1/(1 + E)
(*  -0.*10^-101  *)
```

Comment: A simpler version is `Block[{x0 = 10^-6}, 
 NDSolveValue[{int'[x] == Mod[Ceiling[Log[x]], 2], int[x0] == 0}, 
  int[1], {x, x0, 1}]]`

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks. At some point I gave up on things like `Mod@Floor@Log@x`, before I got to `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fixed it. Thank you to Coolwater for the suggestion.
I did

```
Integrate[
 Piecewise[{{1, Floor[Floor[Log[x]]/2] == Floor[Log[x]]/2}}, 0], {x, 0, 1}]
```

which got rid of the `EvenQ` but still checked that it was even. I then used `NIntegrate` to get an approximate answer and it works, giving me the expected ~0.27. I am still unsure of why it could plot the function but not integrate it, but I got it working.

Comment: What result do you get by executing the integral?  It does not evaluate, when I run it.